# Map over some numeric columns and for each boxplot with a grouping var

Tags: r, ggplot2, purrr

I would like to purrr::map over a df and for each column produce a boxplot with a grouping var. Example attempt:

```
mtcars |> select(am, gear, carb) |> 
  map(~ ggplot() +
        geom_boxplot(aes(y = .x, fill = factor(mtcars$cyl))) +
        labs(title = .y))
```

Outcome:

> Error in dots_list(..., title = title, subtitle = subtitle, caption = caption,  :
> the ... list contains fewer than 2 elements

Desired outcome:

1. `.x` would be the vector/field from the df
2. Using the native pipe placeholder `_`, assign the grouping var `cyl`
3. The title would be the name of the column being plotted. I'm sure I recall seeing `.y` being used here before

How can I purrr::map over the 3 columns am, gear and carb, for each produce a boxplot grouped/split by cyl and using hte native pipe?

Comment: With `purrr::map`, it will not define `.y`, but I'm inferring that you intend for it to be the column name. Use `purrr::imap` and your code works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `purrr::map`, it will not define `.y`, but I'm inferring that you intend for it to be the column name. Use `purrr::imap` and your code works.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(ggplot2)
mtcars |> select(am, gear, carb) |> 
  imap(~ ggplot() +
        geom_boxplot(aes(y = .x, fill = factor(mtcars$cyl))) +
        labs(title = .y))
```

[image: three ggplot images]

Optional, I made the above triple plot with `patchwork`:

```r
library(patchwork)
map(c("am", "gear", "carb"), ~ mtcars |> 
      ggplot() +
        geom_boxplot(aes(y = .data[[.x]], fill = as.factor(cyl))) +
      labs(title = .x)) |>
  Reduce(`+`, x = _)
```

... though this also be done more easily with faceting.

Answer (score 2):

Does this work?

```r
library(tidyverse)

map(c("am", "gear", "carb"), ~ mtcars |> 
      ggplot() +
        geom_boxplot(aes(y = .data[[.x]], fill = as.factor(cyl))) +
      labs(title = .x))
```